# getting null values from form data with sailjs

Tags: post, sails.js, multipartform-data

I've got a post into an api that works ... as long as there is some data posted.
I'm looking for a way to get the null data as well.

Why I'm asking is because I don't know in advance what the parameters will be. The api takes data from a web survey which the client sets up ... without telling me what the fields are going to be. I do know however that all the parameters are being sent in the HTTP Post call.

This is the form data as captured by Charles Proxy

```
    _USERNAME   
    _PASSWORD   
    _TOKEN  
    _RECALLCODE AAA
    _SUBMITTEDDATE  2015.04.21.02.13
    _EDITEDDATE 2015.04.21.02.13
    _COMPLETETYPE   Complete
    _LANGUAGE   en
    _TOTALTIME  311.18
    _SURVEYLINKURL  http://survey.com/AAA
    _RESPONDENTCODE 
    _RESPONDENTTITLE    
    _RESPONDENTFIRSTNAME    
    _RESPONDENTLASTNAME 
    _RESPONDENTSMSID    
    _RESPONDENTPHONE1   
    _RESPONDENTPHONE2   
    _RESPONDENTEMAILADDRESS 
    QUESTION1   TEXT:No
    QUESTION2   TEXT:None+of+the+above
    QUESTION3   TEXT:Nothing
```

This is the result I'm getting

```
    {
      "params": {
        "_RECALLCODE": "AAA",
        "_SUBMITTEDDATE": "2015.04.21.02.13",
        "_EDITEDDATE": "2015.04.21.02.13",
        "_COMPLETETYPE": "Complete",
        "_LANGUAGE": "en",
        "_TOTALTIME": "311.18",
        "_SURVEYLINKURL": "http://survey.com/AAA",
        "QUESTION1": "TEXT:No",
        "QUESTION2": "TEXT:None+of+the+above",
        "QUESTION3": "TEXT:Nothing",
      }
    }
```

This is the result I was expecting.

```
    {
      "params": {
        "_USERNAME": null ,
        "_PASSWORD": null ,
        "_TOKEN": null ,
        "_RECALLCODE": "AAA",
        "_SUBMITTEDDATE": "2015.04.21.02.13",
        "_EDITEDDATE": "2015.04.21.02.13",
        "_COMPLETETYPE": "Complete",
        "_LANGUAGE": "en",
        "_TOTALTIME": "311.18",
        "_SURVEYLINKURL": "http://survey.com/AAA",
        "_RESPONDENTCODE": null ,
        "_RESPONDENTTITLE": null ,
        "_RESPONDENTFIRSTNAME": null ,
        "_RESPONDENTLASTNAME": null ,
        "_RESPONDENTSMSID": null ,
        "_RESPONDENTPHONE1": null ,
        "_RESPONDENTPHONE2": null ,
        "_RESPONDENTEMAILADDRESS": null ,
        "QUESTION1": "TEXT:No",
        "QUESTION2": "TEXT:None+of+the+above",
        "QUESTION3": "TEXT:Nothing",
      }
    }
```

This is the code that checks the parameters within sailjs.

```
 insertResponseByClientCodeAndSurveyCode: function(req,res){

        var responseCode = 200 ;
        var params = req.params.all() ;
        var result = {} ;
        result.params = params ;

        return res.json( responseCode, result ) ;

 } ,
```

How could this be changed to get the null data?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way, in my experience, is set it manually.

```
var params = {
    _USERNAME : req.param('_USERNAME', null),
    _PASSWORD : req.param('_PASSWORD', null),
        ...
    QUESTION3 : req.param('QUESTION3', null)
}
```

Somewhere down the parser chain, the empty fields are dropped. I don't know if this is from body-parser or JSON or what.

Comment: Thanks @metzuda. Why I'm asking is because I don't know in advance what the parameters will be. The api takes data from a web survey which the client sets up ... without telling me what the fields are going to be. I do know however that all the parameters are being sent in the HTTP Post call.